# Distinct for several fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get distinct values of several fields from ElasticSearch index - but it has to be distinct as a set, just like in MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, type from some_table;
```

Until now I have tried some ways to obtain this, but for me all of them failed:

**1. Aggregation**

```
GET test_index/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "track_total_hits": false,
    "aggs" : {
        "features": {
            "terms": {
                "field" : "feature.name",
                "size" : 10,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Script**
This below returns all available combinations for two fields but not only really existing pairs.

```
GET bm_upgraded_visitors/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "t": {
           "terms": {
               "script": "doc['feature.name'].values + ' | ' + doc['feature.type'].values"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
PUT test_index
{
  "mappings" : {
    "_doc" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "features" : {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_root": true,
            "properties" : {
              "name" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              },
              "value" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "type": {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample doc:

```
PUT test_index/_doc/1
{
    "features": [
      {
      "name": "Feature 1",
      "value": "Value 1",
      "type": "Type 1"
      },
      {
      "name": "Feature 2",
      "value": "Value 1",
      "type": "Type 2"
    }
    ]
}
```

Result required:

```
buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Feature 1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "types" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "Type 1",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Feature 2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "types" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "Type 2",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Your second solution would get you what you need, however, have you tried to add a `min_doc_count` of 1 to rule out all empty buckets ?

Comment: I have updated question as there was some redundancy - my second solution gets me all unique values for both fields, but I want unique sets of field1 and field2.

To clarify - as I have `{"field1": "A", "field2": "1"}, {"field1": "B", "field2": "2"}, {"field1": "A", "field2": "1"}, {"field3": "A", "field2: "3"}`, I want to get results like: `{"A", "1"}, {"B", "2"}, {"A", "3"}`, and not like: `{"A", "B"}, {"1", "2", "3"}`

Answer (score 0):

Then you need another terms sub-aggregation. Try this:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "track_total_hits": false,
  "aggs": {
    "features": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "feature.name",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "types": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "feature.type",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: problem is the second aggregation `types` is not narrowed by `features` aggregation so it will contain all unique values for `feature.type` but not stricted to specific `feature.name`

Comment: Even with `min_doc_count` for both? (see updated answer)

Comment: unfortunately yes, even with this request modification

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample data and expected result, so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: sure, I'll add it!

Comment: Ok, but you've omitted a very important information in your initial question: features is `nested`. Also I don't see any "Feature 2" and "Type 2"  in your sample data

Comment: yep, sorry, I should paste sample code in the very beginning. I have just added both "Feature 2" and "Type 2".